# Django ORM query with IN + LIKE

Tags: django, django-models

Lets suppose the following model:

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=False)
    ...
```

I know that I can filter `Persons` with a name that contains the letter `a` using `Person.objects.filter(name__contains='a')`. And I know that I can filter `Persons` with name is in a list using `Person.objects.filter(name__in=['John Doe', 'Mary Jane'])`.

Its possible ( or, whats the performative way ) to do the two things using just one filter ?

I know that I can do 2 queries (maybe more) and fetch the data. But in my current case, I have a method on my view called `get_filters` that returns a `Q` object that will be used in `get_queryset` method. So I need to implement this inside a `Q` object and fetching only 1 query. Its possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly as you figured, you can build up a `Q()` filter object.

```
Q(name__contains='a') & Q(name__in=['John Doe', 'Mary Jane'])
```

However, that will only ever match an object `Mary Jane` since `John Doe` doesn't contain an `a`. (The equivalent SQL is `name LIKE '%a%' AND name IN ('John Doe', 'Mary Jane')`.

If you mean "find any object containing any of these substrings", that's possible too:

```
q = Q()
for substring in ['John', 'Mary', 'Jane']:
  q |= Q(name__contains=substring)
```

This will be the equivalent of `name LIKE '%John%' OR name LIKE '%Mary%' OR name LIKE '%Jane%'`.

Comment: Yeah, what I want to do is "find any object containing any of these substrings", maybe I didn't express myself well but this for loop solves the problem!